# Template for posts of category in block theme?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I am trying to use a custom template for posts of a given category in a block theme. I have created the template file in html (post-show.html). And I have edited the template in the site editor. As I would have done before block themes, I then included this in my functions.php file:

```
// add template by category
function get_custom_template( $single_template ) {
  global $post;
  if ( in_category('show') ) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/post-show.html';
  }
  return $single_template;
}
add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_template" );
```

When I then go to load a post of category "show", WP serves the actual post-show.html file, not the template that has been edited in the site editor.

Any ideas how I should be going about doing this in a block theme instead?

Comment: I don't believe that particular filter is used in block themes, so your HTML file is being loaded the same way a classic theme template would be loaded, and this filter tells WP explicitly that a classic template file is present and should be used, and its name is `templates/post-show.html`. How you would do this in a block theme I'm not sure, but that at least explains why you're getting this behaviour, and that `single_template` isn't an option for an answer

Comment: I appreciate the comment, Tom. And that is exactly what I was thinking. I just wish I knew how to accomplish it in a block theme!

Comment: It seems that the discussion here - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/full-site-editing-templates/ - relates to this issue. But it doesn't offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From reading [this article](https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-use-php-templates-in-block-themes/) I decided to create a post-show.php file and point to that in my get_custom_template function. Then, I took the meat of the post-show template - essentially everything but the header and footer - that I had created in the full site editor and created a template part called "show" out of it. Then, in my post-show.php file, I added all the other parts of the page, called the header and footer using block_header_area() and block_footer_area() and finally added the "show" template part using block_template_part().

It all works. But this largely defeats the purpose of full site editing in that I will have to go in and change this php template file should I want to add other parts to my posts outside the "show" template part (and it would be even worse if I was allowing other users to edit template files in the full site editor). What I think that we would need is some sort of block_template_part function for entire templates. And I am still hoping there is some other solution that I am not yet privy to.